# php function not getting include

Tags: php, function

I have this in index.php

```
require('include\inc\config.inc');
```

When I created a function which require some variable from config.inc
When I run, it says the variable is missing
I need to redeclare the config.inc else the function will never work.
Is there a way to work around?
Now I have this

```
function test(){
require('include\inc\config.inc');
echo $tmp;    
}
```

instead of

```
   require('include\inc\config.inc');
   function test(){    
    echo $tmp;    
    }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Are the variables in your config globals?

Comment: You should also use forward slashes, for portability; and yes they work on DOS/Windows too.

Comment: @BugFinder yes the variables are declared in config.inc

Answer (score 2):

You should read about the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). The `$tmp` variable is global and is not visible inside any function, unless declared with `global`

```
require('include\inc\config.inc');
function test(){    
global $tmp;
echo $tmp;    
}
```

Comment: Yes, although it would be far better to restructure the code so that global variables are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fluent in PHP, but can't you write:

```
require('include\inc\config.inc');
function test() use ($tmp) {
  echo $tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is out of scope in the test() function as previously mentioned and using globals is not considered good practice. You need to pass the variable $tmp into the function test() like this:-

```
function test($tmp)
{
    echo $tmp;
}
```

Then call the function like this:-

```
require_once 'include/inc/configure.inc'
test($tmp);
```